intercept_stream_stream not getting called in grpc.aio [SOLVED]
For some reason when using grpc.io with UnaryUnaryClientInterceptor and StreamStreamClientInterceptor, only the UnaryUnaryClientInterceptor gets called, heres the code in async:
import asyncio
import grpc
from grpc.aio import ClientCallDetails, AioRpcError

import geyser_pb2
import geyser_pb2_grpc


class WithHeaders(
    grpc.aio.UnaryUnaryClientInterceptor,
    grpc.aio.StreamStreamClientInterceptor,
):
    def __init__(self, *headers: tuple[str, str]):
        self.headers = headers

    def _insert_headers(self, new_metadata, client_call_details) -> ClientCallDetails:
        metadata = []
        if client_call_details.metadata is not None:
            metadata = list(client_call_details.metadata)
        metadata.extend(new_metadata)

        return ClientCallDetails(
            method=client_call_details.method,
            timeout=client_call_details.timeout,
            metadata=metadata,
            credentials=client_call_details.credentials,
            wait_for_ready=client_call_details.wait_for_ready,
        )

    async def intercept_unary_unary(self, continuation, client_call_details, request):
        print("intercept unary_unary")
        new_client_call_details = self._insert_headers(
            self.headers, client_call_details
        )
        return await continuation(new_client_call_details, request)

    async def intercept_stream_stream(
        self, continuation, client_call_details, request_iterator
    ):
        print("intercept stream_stream")
        new_client_call_details = self._insert_headers(
            self.headers, client_call_details
        )
        return await continuation(new_client_call_details, request_iterator)


class GeyserClient:
    def __init__(self, channel):
        self.stub = geyser_pb2_grpc.GeyserStub(channel)

    async def get_version(self):
        request = geyser_pb2.GetVersionRequest()
        return await self.stub.GetVersion(request)

    async def subscribe_with_request(self, *requests: geyser_pb2.SubscribeRequest):
        async def request_generator():
            for req in requests:
                yield req

        async for response in self.stub.Subscribe(request_generator()):
            yield response


async def main():
    inter_auth = WithHeaders(("something", "12345"))

    async with grpc.aio.secure_channel(
        "...",
        grpc.ssl_channel_credentials(),
        interceptors=[inter_auth],
    ) as channel:
        client = GeyserClient(channel)

        ver = await client.get_version()
        print(f"{ver=}")

        req = geyser_pb2.SubscribeRequest(
            ...
        )

        async for data in client.subscribe_with_request(req):
            print(data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())

and working code use non-async:
import itertools
import grpc
from grpc import ssl_channel_credentials
from grpc.aio import ClientCallDetails

import geyser_pb2
import geyser_pb2_grpc


class WithHeaders(
    grpc.UnaryUnaryClientInterceptor,
    grpc.StreamStreamClientInterceptor,
):
    def __init__(self, *headers: tuple[str, str]):
        self.headers = headers

    def _insert_headers(self, new_metadata, client_call_details) -> ClientCallDetails:
        metadata = []
        if client_call_details.metadata is not None:
            metadata = list(client_call_details.metadata)
        metadata.extend(new_metadata)

        return ClientCallDetails(
            client_call_details.method,
            client_call_details.timeout,
            metadata,
            client_call_details.credentials,
            False,
        )

    def intercept_unary_unary(self, continuation, client_call_details, request):
        print("intercept unary_unary")
        new_client_call_details = self._insert_headers(
            self.headers, client_call_details
        )
        return continuation(new_client_call_details, request)

    def intercept_stream_stream(
        self,
        continuation,
        client_call_details,
        request_iterator,
    ):
        print("intercept stream_stream")
        new_client_call_details = self._insert_headers(
            self.headers, client_call_details
        )
        return continuation(new_client_call_details, request_iterator)


class GeyserClient:
    def __init__(self, channel):
        self.stub = geyser_pb2_grpc.GeyserStub(channel)

    def get_version(self):
        request = geyser_pb2.GetVersionRequest()
        return self.stub.GetVersion(request)

    def subscribe_with_request(
        self,
        *requests: geyser_pb2.SubscribeRequest,
    ):
        it = iter(requests)
        stream = self.stub.Subscribe(it)
        return stream

def main():
    inter_auth = WithHeaders(("something", "12345"))

    with grpc.secure_channel(
        "...",
        ssl_channel_credentials(),
        options=[("grpc.enable_interceptor", 1)],
    ) as channel:
        channel = grpc.intercept_channel(channel, inter_auth)
        client = GeyserClient(channel)

        ver = client.get_version()
        print(f"{ver=}")

        req = geyser_pb2.SubscribeRequest(
            ...
        )
        for data in client.subscribe_with_request(req):
            print(data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

GetVersion -> unary_unary
Subscribe -> stream_stream
I tried the code in async (grpc.aio) and sync (grpc): expected intercept_stream_stream to work in both implementations, but didn't only in sync

Found the problem, this is a bug related to the way interceptors are added in aio implementation: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/31442
